# Disable Animation if In Progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How do I make this script disable animation if it's already animating?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nav").hover(
            function() {
                $("#header-wrapper").animate({height:140},500);
                $("#dropdown").animate({height:100},500);
            },
            function() {
                $("#header-wrapper").animate({height:40},500);
                $("#dropdown").animate({height:0},500);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I'm really new to jQuery and what I've found through searching hasn't really helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
    $("#nav").hover(
        function() {
            $("#header-wrapper").stop(true,false).animate({height:140},500);
            $("#dropdown").stop(true,false).animate({height:100},500);
        },
        function() {
            $("#header-wrapper").stop(true,false).animate({height:40},500);
            $("#dropdown").stop(true,false).animate({height:0},500);
        }
    );
```

Comment: That did something, but it now rapidly jumps from animated states if you mouse off quickly.

Comment: It should actually be `(true,false)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the .stop() jQuery function

```
$("#dropdown").stop().animate({height:0},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#nav").hover(function() {
    if (!$("#header-wrapper").is(':animated')) {
        $("#header-wrapper").animate({
            height: 140
        },
        500);
        $("#dropdown").animate({
            height: 100
        },
        500);
    } else {
        $("#header-wrapper").stop(true, false).css('height', $("#header-wrapper").height());
        $("#dropdown").stop(true, false).css('height', $('#dropdown').height());
    }
},
function() {
    if (!$("#header-wrapper").is(':animated')) {
        $("#header-wrapper").animate({
            height: 40
        },
        500);
        $("#dropdown").animate({
            height: 0
        },
        500);
    } else {
        $("#header-wrapper").stop(true, false).css('height', $("#header-wrapper").height());
        $("#dropdown").stop(true, false).css('height', $("#dropdown").height());
    }
});
```